# Ionic navigation back button with tabs

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm trying to make work navigation with tabs.

here is a jsfiddle with the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/brayancastrop/fgcruwxg/1/

I have a tabbed view that loads without back button or transition.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/conference.html">
    <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only" has-header=true padding=true>
        <ion-tab title="Info" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline" href="#/events/1/conferences/1/information">
            <ion-nav-view name="conferenceInformation"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Presentation" icon-on="ion-ios7-clock" icon-off="ion-ios7-clock-outline" href="#/events/1/conferences/1/presentation">
            <ion-nav-view name="conferencePresentation"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>

</script>
```

Right now when i go to an event the back button appears correctly in the nav bar, but when i go to a conference, the back button does not appear neither the transition animation.

Maybe i'm using wrong the tabs or missing something on the abstract state but i've tried using hide-back-button in the ion-view for each tab and tried to debug if history has something to do without luck :/

Please, any guidance will be apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have your `<ion-nav-view name="conferenceInformation"></ion-nav-view>` nested inside your `ion-tabs`, which won't work. I think it needs to be above the ion-tabs directive.

Change this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/conference.html">
    <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only" has-header=true padding=true>
        <ion-tab title="Info" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline" href="#/events/1/conferences/1/information">
            <ion-nav-view name="conferenceInformation"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Presentation" icon-on="ion-ios7-clock" icon-off="ion-ios7-clock-outline" href="#/events/1/conferences/1/presentation">
            <ion-nav-view name="conferencePresentation"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>

</script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/conference.html">
    <ion-nav-view name="conferenceInformation"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only" has-header=true padding=true>
        <ion-tab title="Info" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline" href="#/events/1/conferences/1/information">

        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Presentation" icon-on="ion-ios7-clock" icon-off="ion-ios7-clock-outline" href="#/events/1/conferences/1/presentation">
            <ion-nav-view name="conferencePresentation"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>

</script>
```

[Updated  jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51w9xo5j/)

Comment: Awesome! I've read your example and changed some of my codes... Now I have navigation between side-menu and tabs! :D